# Tokina 100mm Macro f2.8 D wont autofocus on a Nikon D7500

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, tokina

I just got this camera recently with the lens aformentioned, however upon usage, I wasn't able to autofocus anymore. Any fix?

Comment: Is there a AF/MF-switch? If yes, move it to the AF position.

Answer (score 1):

Likely this is because you haven't switched on "autofocus" on the lens itself, move the slide from MF to AF:

[image]

Move the slide from MF to AF

Answer (score 1):

This lens does not have an autofocus motor in the lens. It must use the AF motor in the camera body to drive the lens focus.

Make sure the lens’s push-pull AF switch, and the camera’s AF switch are BOTH set to AF.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have fixed the problem, I actually pushed down the lens a bit when mounting it on the body, kind of like what I do with an aps-c Canon body and its EF lenses but that was the reason it didn't work.

However, simply inserting the lens mount on to the camera and simply rotating it without pushing the lens a bit solved the issue.

I firmly took note of this, as I was at a risk of crushing the components of the camera.